Use "Authorization" header instead of "x-api-key" to access private api of AWS API Gateway
Is there a way I can use Authroization header (with Bearer) instead of x-api-key to access the Privet API of AWS API Gateway

What kind of API Gateway that you are using? HTTP or REST?
For access control, you can create a Lambda Authorizer for REST API API Gateway with either Regional or Private type.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html
From the Authorizer configuration, you can set the Header to be Authorization as you mentioned.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization.html

Thanks for your response, I'm using REST API - How can I validate a API Key generated by API Gateway? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html

@BhanwarlalChaudhary For validation, you can use tools such as Postman or CURL (Bash) to test your APIs. Ensure that your APIs are configured with API Key required during the setup.
